# Docker: use file in local folder

Tags: docker

I try to run this line via docker (in my home directory, where also the image is):

```
sudo docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/ne/input -it alexjc/neural-enhance --zoom=1 --model=repair myimage.jpg
```

This runs fine. However, it cannot find the image. How to set the path correctly? (something with the -v argument I think, but could not find how to use it)

The Python error is

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myimage.jpg'

Comment: It seems like it cannot find the vlcsnap.png image, rather than myimage.jpg? Where is vlcsnap.png on your machine?

Comment: sorry typo, in my home directory

Answer (score 4):

The image won't be available in the Docker image, unless you include it at build time or make it available via volume mounting.

You should replace the command line with:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/ne/input -v `pwd`/myimage.jpg:/path/to/myimage.jpg -it alexjc/neural-enhance --zoom=1 --model=repair /path/to/myimage.jpg
```

Comment: Okay thanks, this command works without errors. Do you also have an idea where the resulting image is written to? I cannot see it

Comment: The resulting image is in the running container. You need to mount it like the input file, or get it out via docker cp, while the container is running.

Comment: Okay thanks again, this is the first time I am using Docker. Do you have a command? If I use this: docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target what is the <containerId>?

Comment: Use `docker ps` to see all the running containers and the images they are based off. The container id should be printed. Use `docker ps -a` to see all containers, even stopped ones. If this is a one-off command, the container will be stopped afterwards, and it might not allow copying stuff out of it. Be careful with Docker. It's definitely neat and once you get the hang of it, very useful for development and even production. But it has somewhat of a learning curve, and it can be frustrating in situations like this to bang your head.